# How can I allow only HTML into my database?

Tags: php, html, database, mysql-real-escape-string, strip-tags

I'm trying to allow the user to input only HTML into a form, and on submit, store it into the database. I've been trying to use `mysql_real_escape_string`, but the PHP I put into the form with the HTML tags seems to not be stripped. How can I "filter" what is stored into the database?

**EDIT:**
I want to keep the HTML as-is. So, say a user inputs

```
<input type="text"/>
```

and hits submit; I want that to be entered into the database without any problems, and then later on down the road, be able to show up on their post.

I want to get rid of things such as PHP tags:

```
<input type="text"/>
<?php echo "Hello World!"; ?> <-- I do not want to store this.
```

If it's still not making any sense I will try my best to explain it a little better.

Comment: Stripping HTML tags is not `mysql_real_escape_string`'s task. Can you describe what exactly you want (do you want to strip HTML tags, or show them as clear text, or want them interpreted?) and show the code you are using for input and output?

Comment: You've only only touched the surface here.  What exactly are you trying to filter out, and do you have code to show?

Comment: Ideally, you should store *precisely* what the user supplies, escaping it (mysql_real_escape_string, or via PDO, mysqli parameters, etc) for DB storage and then carry out the filtering on output. By doing this, you'll ensure no loss of precision.

Comment: Suggest remove the html tag.  This is not an html question.

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to parse the HTML and strip out unwanted tags.  This is a relatively trivial with a decent parser, such as the [PHP XML Parser](http://php.net/manual/en/book.xml.php).